# Alpha calculation for anti aliased line

Tags: antialiasing, line-drawing

Seems like there are two techniques

- `Interpolation`: Interpolate the minimum distance from the canter of the pixel to the line.
- `Coverage`: The fraction of the pixel covered by the line

Are the results the same?

For interpolation, are the edges always linearly interpolated?

What about for the intersection of two lines? I imagine coverage would make better sense?